# pelican/rst2html codeblock error

Tags: restructuredtext, pelican

This piece of Restructuredtext (Cleaning up and the code is preceding and following text).

```
    Cleaning up...

.. code-block::

    from sqlobject import StringCol, SQLObject, ForeignKey, sqlhub, connectionForURI

    sqlhub.processConnection = connectionForURI('sqlite:/:memory:')

    class Person(SQLObject):
        name = StringCol()
        class Address(SQLObject):
        address = StringCol()
        person = ForeignKey('Person')

        Person.createTable()
        Address.createTable()

The code
```

Is built correctly by rst2html but generates following error when I try to process it with Pelican (pelican content command):

> (ERROR/3) Error in "code-block" directive: 1 argument(s) required, 0
>   supplied.

How can I solve this? I tried various indentations, with and without empty line between codeblock and actual code…

Comment: How about `.. code-block:: python`? The code looks like Python.

Comment: Thanks, working now. I thought it defaulted to python. I know better now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this question I can paraphrase the comment of mzjn. Adding Python to the line ..code-block solved the problem.